# Why use mem_fn?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I'm confused as to why `std::mem_fn` is needed.

I have a function that takes in any callable (lambda, function pointer, etc),and binds it to an argument.

Eg:

```
template<class T>
void Class::DoBinding(T callable) {
  m_callable = std::bind(callable, _1, 4);
}
//somewhere else
Item item;
m_callable(item);
```

All code samples I've seen do:

```
//some defined member function
Item::Foo(int n);

DoBinding(std::mem_fn(&Item::Foo));
```

Why can't it simply be:

```
DoBinding(&Item::Foo);
```

It seems the latter is callable without having to use std::mem_fn, so why is it needed?

Comment: No, you don't need `mem_fn` for that. You do need it for other stuff.

Comment: You should never pass to `std::bind` a value of an unknown type. If the type is itself a bind expression, then the behaviour is surprising. In other words, `std::bind` should be used in leaf code, not in generic code.

Comment: What about using a lambda instead of std::bind? I feel that the syntax is more legible, and when you get around to using C++14 it should cover all (nearly all?) the same use cases that bind has

Comment: @AndyG Except the "nearly all" doesn't actually cover the case that OP is asking about.

Comment: @Barry: But it should with C++14, no? I realize the tag is C++11, so perhaps the comment was a bit misdirected.

Answer (score 27):

This is because generic code that expects `UnaryFunction` or `BinaryFunction` will invoke it directly with the regular call syntax. So to pick an arbitrary algorithm like [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), it could well be implemented like:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        f(*first); // <== N.B. f(*first)
    }
    return f;
}
```

If you called `for_each()` with `&Item::Foo`, the code try to call `(&Item::Foo)(x)`, which is ill-formed since for pointers to members you have to write `(x.*&Item::Foo)()`. It's that syntactical difference that `mem_fn` is meant to solve: `mem_fn` deals with the invocation syntax of pointers to members so that you can use all the algorithms with pointers to members as well as functions and function objects. You cannot have `for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), &Item::Foo)` but you can have `for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), mem_fn(&Item::Foo))`.

This works just fine in `std::bind()` (and `std::thread` and `std::function` and ...) natively since those all have explicit handling for pointers to members separately. And since `DoBinding()` itself calls `std::bind()`, there is no reason for `std::mem_fn` *in this case*.

---

There <s>is</s> was a proposal to get rid of this syntactic difference: [P0312](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0312r0.pdf). It did not go well.

Comment: It looks as though that proposal is dead:

https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Bjarne-Stroustrup-reject-the-proposal-to-make-pointers-to-functions-directly-callable

Answer (score 17):

This is usually done because the person who writes `DoBinding(std::mem_fn(&Item::Foo))` has no idea that `DoBinding` can take a member pointer directly.

Remember: `std::sort(..., &Item::Foo)` will *fail*, because `sort` expects the value to be a directly-callable function object. And member pointers *are not*. Indeed, pretty much every algorithm in the C++ standard library will fail when given a member pointer instead of a directly-callable type. Your `DoBinding` only works because you're using `std::bind`, which has a special overload for member pointers. The caller of `DoBinding` doesn't necessarily know you're doing that.

Most code that takes callables by template parameters will choke on a member pointer. So to be safe, we don't pass member pointers around as objects that can be directly called; use `mem_fn` to turn it into such an object.